# Laravel login without encrypt password in sql server

Tags: php, sql, laravel, web

I want to login in with sql server data, I want to login with vcUsuario as user and vcclave as password, is it possible to use make:auth configuration to login with these credentials without encrypting vcclave? or do I need to make and encryptyng in sql server data? please help [image]

Comment: i don't try `sql server` with laravel before but there is a function called `BCrypt` in laravel use it before save your user in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can login to a user in laravel use `Auth::login($user);`.

It's better to encrypt your password to have a safer website but you can create login form and custom login function in your Controller without encrypting.

Example code after check your password is correct in collection :

```
if($correct){
   Auth::login($user);
   return redirect('/home');
}else{
   return redirect('/login');
}
```

$user is your user login data that you can get it from collection with code like this :

```
$user = User::whereUsername($username)->wherePassword($password)->first();
```

But It's better to change name of vsUsuario to vs_usuraio and vcclave to vc_clave.